# How to append the Leaflet.js attribution string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to [customize the attribution section of a Leaflet.js map](https://github.com/wo-ist-markt/wo-ist-markt.github.io/pull/208). The custom part of the attribution is everything that follows `Leaflet |` as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Leaflet.js map with attribution]

My custom attribution string is added as follows:

```
var ATTRIBUTION = '...'
var map;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tiles = new L.TileLayer(TILES_URL, {attribution: ATTRIBUTION});
    map = new L.Map('map').addLayer(tiles);
    // ...
});
```

Leaflet.js adds itself to the **front** of my existing attribution string which can be seen in the [sources](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Attribution.js). How can I **append** the Leaflet attribution string instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do here is to remove the original attribution so that you can create a new one without the "Leaflet prefix".

First disable the default attribution control:

```
var map = L.map('map', {attributionControl: false}).setView(latLng, 13);
```

Then create a new attribution control without the default Leaflet prefix(do this before you add any layers):

```
L.control.attribution({prefix: ''}).addTo(map);
```

Now all attributions in Layer options will be added to your new control.

Note that this does remove the "Leaflet" part entirely if you still want it last in your attribution string you will need to add it to the rest of your attributions.

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/abbe98/14cw26od/).